# substring-before() and substring-after problem in webkit engine based browser

Tags: xslt, webkit

Below you may see xslt code to produce radiobuttons. It works on firefox and opera but not on arora(uses webkit engine). Briefly I didn't try it any other browsers use webkit engine

```
<xsl:template name="createRadioButton">
        <xsl:param name="list" /><!-- something like : true|false|bla|bla -->
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" /> <!-- "|" -->
        <xsl:param name="nameofradio" /> <!-- sampleName -->
        <xsl:param name="valueofradio" /> <!-- sampleValue -->
        <xsl:variable name="newlist">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($list), $delimiter)"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:variable>
          <!-- problem is these two lines. When I assign something else it works.-->
          <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)" />
          <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)" />
          <xsl:element name="input">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$nameofradio"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of  select="$first"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@hassection='true'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">showHiddenTable(this.value);validateFormElement(this.name,this.value);</xsl:attribute>        
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$valueofradio = $first">
                    <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">validateFormElement(this.name,this.value)</xsl:attribute>        
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:value-of select="$first" />
          <xsl:if test="$remaining">
              <xsl:call-template name="createRadioButton">
                  <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" />
                  <xsl:with-param name="delimiter"><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/></xsl:with-param>
                  <xsl:with-param name="nameofradio"><xsl:value-of select="$nameofradio"/></xsl:with-param>
                  <xsl:with-param name="valueofradio"><xsl:value-of select="$valueofradio"/></xsl:with-param>
              </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

I searched the web did not see anyone had my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for confirmation that the code performs OK in any other XSLT processor.

Answer (score 3):

This transformation produced the expected results when I performed it with every one of the 9 XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) processors that I am using.

I am calling your template in the following way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <table>
  <xsl:call-template name="createRadioButton">
   <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'true|false|bla|bla'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="nameofradio" select="'Phillips'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="valueofradio" select="200"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </table>  
</xsl:template>
```

**Therefore, this seems as a bug** -- report it to the vendor.